# Visual Studio 2019 not underlining errors in C++ projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I would like VS2019 to underline errors in real time, so when I compile, I do not get errors that could have otherwise been detected before the build process.

Currently, I have to build to get the errors, and nothing gets underlined; I have to use the ErrorList to find the errors. It is messing with my workflow. Android Studio and Eclipse both underline errors in real time, and I would like to know how to get Visual Studio 2019 to do the same for C++ projects.

I have checked settings in Tools->Options->TextEditor->C++->Acvanced. The settings look correct.

Comment: Is VS syntax highlighting the files in question?

Comment: VS uses intellisense for this. Make sure it is turned on (should be by default)

Comment: Intellisense often goes screwy. Quit Visual Studio, find the `.vs` directory in your project folder (it may be hidden) and delete it. Then try again. No guarantees but it often helps.

Comment: It did go screwy. I figured out the problem and once fixed the error highlighting came back. I think it was a problem with macros that screwed it up.